# How do I replace the a value in a pandas series with another?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace all the values of "Red" with "Trust". How would it work because there are multiple values in each cell?

Input:

```
                Explanation
0  Green, Yellow, Blue, Red
1          Red, Green, Blue
2                       Red
3        Blue, Pink, Yellow
```

Desired Output:

```
                  Explanation
0  Green, Yellow, Blue, Trust
1          Trust, Green, Blue
2                       Trust
3          Blue, Pink, Yellow
```

I've used .replace but it only changed the cell where it's only "red" with no other colors included. Please help!

Comment: It wasn't clear with your original formatting, are the contents of each cell a list or a string?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`pd.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), `pd.Series.replace` only replaces if the *whole cell* matches.

```
df.Explanation = df.Explanation.str.replace('Red', 'Trust', regex=False)
print(df)

# Output:

                  Explanation
0  Green, Yellow, Blue, Trust
1          Trust, Green, Blue
2                       Trust
3          Blue, Pink, Yellow
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use `replace` with `dict` and `regex=True`

```
df = df.replace({'Explanation' :{'Red' : 'Trust'}},regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

###### You can replace the substring in a column of pandas DataFrame as following methods.

- To replace single substring :

  `df = df.replace('Red','Trust', regex=True)`
- To replace multiple column substring :

  `df = df.replace({'Explanation1': 'Red', 'Explanation2': 'Pink'}, {'Explanation1': 'Red', 'Explanation2': 'Hope'}, regex=True)`
- Replace using lambda function :

  `df = df.apply(lambda x: x.replace('Red':'Red',regex=True))`

*Hope this helped you. Thank you.*